# Best way to pass data between multiples ViewControllers in Swift

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, singleton, segue

I have a form divided in multiples `ViewController`. Each one with an unique `TextField`. I wonder which is the best way to pass data through. Overriding each `prepareForSegue` method, using a unique Singleton class which contains the data or any other alternative?

Comment: I would suggest using NSUserDefaults. It's quick and easy and you can read and write the saved data from anywhere in your app.

Comment: As above, `NSUserDefaults` is good for simple things.  If your data is larger, more complex, or needs verification rules, you can create a custom class to act as the app's data model and access it as a shared instance (Singleton-ish).